# joomla mysql date math logic

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, logic

I am trying to create a condition through php & mysql that a user can submit in maximum 5 submissions in 24 hours time clause of a formid

```
// Define the maximum number of submissions for 24 hours
$max = 5;

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$query   = $db->getQuery(true);

// Setup the query.
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').')')
    ->from($db->qn('#__rs_submissions'))
    ->where($db->qn('FormId').'='.$db->q($formId))
    ->where($db->qn('Username').'='.$db->q($user->get('username')));
    ->where($db->qn('DateSubmitted').'>='.$db->q('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))

$db->setQuery($query);
$counter = $db->loadResult();

if ($counter >= $max){
  $formLayout = '<p style="color:blue;">Oops !! Your Limits are Exhausted for 24 hours </p>';
}
}
```

Here is the Database Table Values
[image]

The Query is not respecting in the date time condition of 24 hour period

```
 ->where($db->qn('DateSubmitted').'>='.$db->q('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))
```

can someone help and advise - what am i doing wrong and solution for respecting limit of 24 hours

**Edit**
I guess -   count of ($db->qn('DateSubmitted').'>='.$db->q('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')) should be done - along with last recorded time should be base for calculating 24 hour gap, Still unsure as is unable to achieve the desired

Starting Bounty - can someone help on it.

Comment: This is Joomla right?

Comment: yes, but does it make a difference for the cms type ?

Comment: First i just want to tag your question right

Comment: Second there are a whole lot of mysql devs here that can answer your question quick, but not if it has to be in joomla code objects as that becomes real niche

Comment: Have you tried with `<=` instead of `>=`?

Comment: Hello - Yes - in that case - it always states - limits are exhausted. So even if there is 1 submission then imposing <= will display the message - Your Limits are Exhausted for 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to quote the function. If you do so the final query you will get will be:

```
DateSubmitted >= 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'
```

And this is not what you want. 
Since the content of that part is something you know (and not a string you get from the user) you don't need to quote it. You should use it as is:

```
 ->where($db->qn('DateSubmitted'). ' >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
```

Comment: Yes it works like a charm, i was mistakenly using same - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of NOW use CURDATE

->where($db->qn('DateSubmitted').'>='.$db->q('CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')

Comment: Doesnt have any impact of this rule as mentioned ->where($db->qn('DateSubmitted').'>='.$db->q('CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))